# Nighly Postgres related job in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Sorry i am very new to AWS and looking for the correct solution to implement following.

I need to build a job ( C# preferbly, since rest of the code is developed in c#) that will run nightly ( once in 24 hours hopefully ) to get some records from a postgress database table(s) and update the status based on a pre-defined condition.

What is the best way to implement this in AWS with postgress.

Comment: What do you mean by "update the status"? Is this something within the same PostgreSQL database? Feel free to edit the question to provide more details.

Comment: Yes, a simple update query whcih will change the status of some records based on pre-defined condition. In a typical windows env, this can be easily done using a Schedule job, but not sure the correct way to implement this in AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to trigger an SQL Client (running *somewhere*) that will connect to the PostgreSQL database and run the desired queries.

This could be done from:

- An Amazon EC2 instance
- A computer anywhere on the Internet
- An AWS Lambda function

If you have a Windows instance running somewhere, feel free to use it (be it on EC2 or elsewhere).

Alternatively, you could create an **AWS Lambda function** that connects to the database and runs the desired commands. The Lambda function can be assigned a schedule to **run on a regular basis**.

See: [Schedule Expressions Using Rate or Cron - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)

AWS Lambda functions can be written in a variety of languages, including .Net core.

Comment: Thanks alot, i will attempt this, and see if it works for my situation.

Comment: if possible can you please also answer my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432461/moving-net-core-web-api-to-aws-web-api-gateway